# TCP transport for grpc-java

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

Is there an implementation of raw TCP transport for grpc-java? I need grpc for internal network services and don't have firewall issues so I'd like to avoid HTTP/2 overhead when building grpc based services.

Comment: You may have more luck asking in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/grpc-io but keep in mind that this question may not receive a good response because it doesn't sound like you have done any work to identify http as a performance blocker.  Also HTTP uses TCP so really you want an alternate implementation to HTTP that might be faster?

Comment: Care to elaborate why the downvote(s)?

Comment: Asking "is there" instead of finding out yourself is the reason I downvoted. What is this, a glorified Google? Also Deadron's point, are you prematurely optimizing or do you have hard proof that you'll get an advantage in taking HTTP/2 out of the mix?

Comment: @Kayaman I asked is there because I couldn't find it. I found it for go lang but not for java on google groups mailing list. Why are you assuming that I don't know why I need raw TCP instead of HTTP/2. My question is specifically to find if there's "after-market" implementations that may not be so easy to find.

Comment: @hawk considering how little information there is in your question, I assumed that you hadn't done much research and possibly don't fully know what you're doing. It's your job to write your questions so clearly that others don't have to make assumptions about your competence or lack thereof. Two lines of text does not a good question make.

Comment: really so when i write HTTP/2 overhead tagging the question grpc, i have to also explain what the overhead is? do i also explain what tcp and grpc are because you can assume I didn't do my "research" there either. @Kayaman

Comment: default grpc transports are using TCP. also, grpc is using http2 protocol, so the questions doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @creamsoup java gets compiled to machine code so if someone asks how can I do it in assembly does it not make sense as well?

Comment: maybe if you don't use the term "compiled". seems like terminologies you are using is off. also you should specify which architecture/OS you are targeting (too vague). your example inherits exactly same problems of the question.

Answer (score -1):

"Raw" TCP is not actually a thing. You need to build a protocol on top. It happens that HTTP/2 is very close to any proprietary protocol gRPC might make. I'll also note that gRPC integrates closely with HTTP/2, so HTTP/2 is viewed as part of gRPC within many implementations and can be optimized as one unit.

gRPC needs multiplexing, flow control, byte-based framing (not message-based), and metadata. And that's basically what HTTP/2 is at its heart. You can make simpler protocols, but then you begin having issues with large messages causing head-of-line blocking, memory usage, or frequent TLS connection establishment costs.

Making a protocol with those features is a very well understood problem. HTTP/2 actually looks more similar to TCP than HTTP/1 in many respects. And it solved the problems in mostly the same way as SSH-2.

The "losses" by choosing HTTP/2 are small. Things like required headers used in grpc, like method name and status code, can't be optimized directly into the protocol as a struct instead of generic metadata. But HPACK can help some there. Native binary headers would be really nice, to avoid base64-encoding metadata, although it would be relatively easy to extend HTTP/2 to support that via a SETTINGS negotiation.

Comment: I don't need TLS and I certainly don't need per frame stream identification overhead as well. Some multiplexing is all I need without any flow control. I take it that flow control is optional at the channel layer if not transport layer in gRPC

Comment: and there is a tcp based go implementation apparently so this doesn't answer anything. is there a java TCP transport for gRPC?

Comment: It's the same problem with HTTP/3 as well. Built in TLS for inner network comms is useless overhead.

Comment: TLS is not required for gRPC. If you have multiplexing, you need per-frame stream identification unless you don't support large messages. And flow control is mandatory for grpc streams. It sounds like you want a custom protocol just for yourself.